# load more with ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hello here i have a problem with load more ajax all is okey but when there is no
data to show from database show me this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6158Y.png

index.php

```
<div id="show_here">
<div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $post['id']; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
// Load more post
function show_more_posts(post_id)
{
    var ID = post_id;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/ajax_more.php",
    data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#show_here").append(html);
        $("#hide_here").remove();
    }
    });
    return false;
}
```

ajax_more.php

```
 <?php
include("../config.php");

$lastmsg = $_POST['lastmsg'];
$result = mysqli_query($Connection, "select * from posts where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $msg_id=$row['id'];
    $message=$row['text']; ?>

    <li> <?php echo $message; ?> </li> <?php
}
?>

<div id="show_here">
    <div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $msg_id; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use "GET" method for retrieving the data if you use `echo` as output.

Comment: declare $msg_id=''; before loop

Comment: you shoule be define $msg_id before while

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do like this

```
<div id="show_here">
<?php
if(isset($post['id'])) {
?>
    <div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $post['id']; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
<?php
}else{
?>
<div id="hide_here">No More Posts to show !!!!</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Try this, it may help you

Comment: @C0dekid may I know how my answer is invalid?

Comment: @C0dekid did you mean the <?php ?> Tags? Then it is shameful to know that a person like you who can't assume PHP Tags over there down voted my answer lol

Comment: Hold on, let me edit your answer, than you can see what i mean, if you aprove the edit, I will upvote your answer, because someone downvoted it due some errors in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. then you will not get error.

```
<?php
if(isset($msg_id)) {
?>
<div id="show_here">
    <div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $msg_id; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax_more.php file you have to set `$msg_id` to `$lastmsg` before the while:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");

$lastmsg = $_POST['lastmsg'];
$result = mysqli_query($Connection, "select * from posts where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 10");

$msg_id = $lastmsg;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $msg_id=$row['id'];
    $message=$row['text']; ?>

    <li> <?php echo $message; ?> </li> <?php
}
?>

    <div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $msg_id; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
```

so, even if your query doesn't return data (no new messages), the variable have the correct value.

If, instead, you expect that at some point, there aren't more posts to load, you have to use the solution provided also from Kaja Mydeen:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");

$lastmsg = $_POST['lastmsg'];
$result = mysqli_query($Connection, "select * from posts where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 10");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $msg_id=$row['id'];
    $message=$row['text']; ?>

    <li> <?php echo $message; ?> </li> <?php
}
?>

<?php if(isset($msg_id)) { ?>
    <div id="hide_here" onclick="show_more_posts(<?php echo $msg_id; ?>);">Show More Posts</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, your code have somethin strange: you continue to add a `div` with and `id="show_here"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think before fetch data through while loop you should have check for total affected rows like this

```
$totrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($totrows > 0){
  //your while loop for fetch data
}else{
  //return something else
}
```